# What is the relationship among the solutions of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose g(x) a positive real function, then the systems of ordinary differential equations

$x'=f(x,y)\\
y'=h(x,y)$

and

$x'=g(x)f(x,y)\\
y'=h(x,y)$

have the same phase portrait?

NOTE: In Chicone-2006(Ordinary Differential Equations with Applications), show that

$x'=f(x,y)\\
y'=h(x,y)$

and

$x'=g(x)f(x,y)\\
y'=g(x)h(x,y)$

have the same phase portraits.

Comment: As a counter-example to the first conjecture, check $f(x, y) = x$, $h(x, y) = -y$ and $g(x) = x$. The first system has hyperbolic saddle, but the second one has non-hyperbolic saddle-node with different phase portrait.